# Why would IPS vendor provider refuse to publish SLAs to fix the published highly ranked CVEs?

Tags: ids, threat-mitigation, cve, updates, threats

One of the biggest IPS providers (top of Gartner graph for its category) is not providing SLAs for all the 7+ ranking CVEs published last year. I don't really understand why would they refuse to provide SLAs for the published CVEs and I was wondering if Its a common practice?

Comment: I think any answer would be primarily opinion-based, because you've cited no specific vendor or market vertical. Maybe the vendors just don't care? Or maybe they just typically serve a market that wouldn't track CVEs or value SLAs? There could be a ton of reasons, including just not wanting to make a commitment that they're not sure they would be able to keep.

Comment: Are they providing SLAs for some of the CVEs?